# wcf - why can't I desealize a string array using the client

Tags: wcf

I have the following in my client but I can't seem to deserialise the json into the UserRoleGetResult

```
 public class WCFRootObject
    {
       public SignInResult SignInResult { get; set; }
       public bool UserIsInRoleResult { get; set; }
       public bool ChangePasswordRequiredResult { get; set; }

       public UserRoleGetResultWrapper UserRoleGetResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRoleGetResultWrapper
    {
        public string[] UserRoleGetResult { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the json it returns

```
 {
      "UserRoleGetResult": [
        "MarbleAccess",
        "MartinAccess",
        "OLBAccess",
        "SuperUser",
        "Supervisor"
      ]
    }
```

Is there some documentation I;ve not read which explains how I should of implemented the rootObject?

why?

Comment: are you looking for webmessagebodystyle , have  a look :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you are tiring to deserilize the json object into `WCFRootObject`. please try deserilzing your json into this object:

```
 public class WCFRootObject
    {
       public SignInResult SignInResult { get; set; }
       public bool UserIsInRoleResult { get; set; }
       public bool ChangePasswordRequiredResult { get; set; }

       public string[] UserRoleGetResult { get; set; }
    }
```

you wrapped the object twice.

Comment: Oh yeah I did try that first but it didn't work. OK I must be doing something stupid somewhere else thanks mohammad.

Comment: any time dear @Ageis